# java, evaluating extensive use of URL instead of File

Tags: java, file, url

In a java desktop application, I often use references to files.
So far i've constructed File objects as soon as possible, and then pass File objects to methods, for example:

```
public void loadConfig(File configFile) {
    ...
}
```

I'm evaluating an extensive replacement of `File` with `URL`.
This primarily because URL can easily reference a file into a zip or jar file.

Does URL have SecurityManager issues (when referring to a local file) that File class wouldn't have for the same file?

Since this refactoring impacts the interfaces and not only the implementations, i'm also intrested in any other consideration on this "replacement".

Answer (score 3):

The main issues you'll probably encounter:

- When constructing URLs, you have to handle the `MalformedURLException`. File constructor doesn't throw this exception.
- You lose many File-based convenience methods, such as: does the file exist; is it a file or directory; is it readable; set file as readable or writeable. Since the URL may not reference a file, these don't necessarily apply and aren't available in the URL API.
- The way you access the URL changes. URL has `openStream` or `openConnection` methods; with File you'd probably use a file-based stream (`FileInputStream` for example).
- If the URL requires network, rather than disk access, any assumptions on latency you may have made may no longer hold.

The URL class does make some SecurityManager checks, but given it's a desktop application, don't you have control over the security manager settings?

Other than that, since URL is a superset of file (in that it handles the `file:` protocol among other things), you should be able to use it in the same way. Another option -- instead of passing either File or URL -- is to use streams wherever possible, since you can then use either a file or a URL to generate the stream, as required.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of streams.  They can not only handle file or URL based sources, but even data generated at run-time in memory (`ByteArrayInputStream`).

Comment: +1, for the accuracy. "don't you have control over the security manager settings?". i find that in java desktop area there is a chronic lack of "well established" procedures. This app is supposed to run on a 3-5 hundreds of machines, not of a single organization. On one hand I don't know java "InstallShield"s, that is a software that wraps up my application and manages the JVM security manager settings for me too. On the other hand, as far as I can see, default installations of JRE on clients, gives applications high priviledges on machines, and I'm tempted to rely on this fact.

Comment: @AgostinoX I think you're right: I imagine most installations have all the privileges of the user who started the application. However, I haven't ever had to deploy to "locked down" environments, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: "instead of passing either File or URL is to use streams wherever possible" this is a very very intresting architectural issue that is not strictly an "api-specification".I'm very intrested in this topic, maybe I will post something on 'programmers'.The idea i'm working on is that there are classes that manage "live objects", e.g. ConfigurationLoader, XmlConfigReader and so on.Passing to them Streams instead of a reference enforces the single-rexponsibility principle!They just manage the content of the file and not the way the file is accessed (disk or web) nor "caching" nor locking issues.

Comment: but there are also classes that manages references: i have a root directory, that in turn contains configuration files, sub directories with application resources. The idea is: grouping this "references" togheter AND keep them separated from classes that manages "live" objects. while doing this, i've encountered URL, that is something capable of a "more general", or more universal ability to rapresent the position of something. An intresting fact is that while file represents a file system object, it's natural use it to represent a dir. While accessing a directory via URL seems not possible

Answer (score 1):

> Does URL have SecurityManager issues (when referring to a local file) that File class wouldn't have for the same file?

No.

A sand-boxed app. only has access to URLs on its own class-path, but anything that can create and use a `File` is running with all-permissions.